# Rotate PDF in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

In Safari if I open a misoriented PDF is there a way to rotate it so that I can read it without having to rotate my head and end up dizzy?

Answer (score 3):

If it's mis-oriented in Safari that means the original is formatted that way.  Safari only provides a "quick viewer" of sorts for PDF files and is only rendering what was provided.

### What you need to do is open it in Preview.

[image]

Simply right click anywhere on the PDF in Safari and select "Open With Preview."  Once you're in Preview, you can rotate the PDF with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to rotate left and right respectively.

Comment: This doesn't actually Open with Preview. It seems to open with the default PDF viewer. My default PDF viewer is unfortunately Safari...

Comment: Are you right clicking on the *rendered* PDF or the link?

Comment: When you right click on the rendered PDF in Safari, you should get the option to open in Preview - this is the default behavior.

Comment: Try option click.  Did you modify the default behavior(s) of your mouse?

Comment: Because I'm asking you to right click (your mouse) and you're giving me results that are not consistent with what should be happening.  When you right click, you should get a *menu*, not a new tab with the link's location in the address bar.

Comment: That means there's something going on with Preview like PDF files are now associated with something else or some other setting related to PDFs/Safari/Downloads/Preview that's not standard.  In your case, save the file instead of opening it for now.  But this behavior actually creates a new question re:  the default behavior of opening PDF's in Safari.

Comment: that needs to be changed because what renders a PDF in Safari is a simple plug in, not Preview.  This can cause major issues further down the road.  Find a PDF file and press `Cmd-I` or right click and select "Get Info"  Check to see what the file "Opens With" (about midway down)

Comment: I set Safari as the default because I prefer using it to view PDFs normally. What are the "major issues" this can cause?

Comment: This - the rotate issue.  Forms will be another.  Printing...because you'll be printing it as a web page, not as a PDF document.  Safari renders web pages, it's not a PDF reader.  It can render a PDF because there's a plugin/add-on, but it's not a PDF viewer.

Comment: You can create an action or an "Open With" menu item for PDFs, but by associating the PDF with an app that's not designed for it, you created a circular issue by which the app that can only do a "quick look" is now what is called when you need advanced tools like rotate.

Comment: I think it's Apple's fault that 'Open with Preview' doesn't actually open with Preview.app. It's clearly a bug: either a mislabelling of that context menu option, or it's pointing at the wrong action.

Comment: Regardless...you're associated the PDF file with an App not designed to be a PDF reader.  Your fix is to put it back to it's default.  That way you'll get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Preview is a terrific alternative as mentioned above.
Preview can even save the PDF with the new rotation. Later, if you want to view in Safari, you can do so without difficulty (or dizziness).